QR Code scanning and generation. When I go to scan the QR code I want it to display some plain text information, instead I am shown "no usable info"
So I am working on a python script that generates a QR code that contains info, which are email, name, id, and a website to redirect to when scanned. I successfully created the generation of the QR code here:
def generate_qr_code_redirect_and_id(name, email, redirect_url):
    # Generate ID
    id = generate_id(name, email)
    
    # Construct data for QR code including the GIF URL
    data = f"ID: {id}\nName: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nRedirectURL: {redirect_url}\nGIF: https://gifdb.com/images/high/spongebob-squarepants-done-and-done-2de4g1978uus7pp6.gif"
    
    # Generate QR code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    qr_image = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    
    # Convert image to bytes
    qr_buffer = BytesIO()
    qr_image.save(qr_buffer, format='PNG')
    qr_image_data = qr_buffer.getvalue()
    
    return id, qr_image_data

I also got the data to be uploaded to a MongoDB cluster and I also got it saved automatically in a csv file.
The problem is when I go scan the QR code, it shows on my phone no usable information.
Here is the rest of the code (all imports done):
def generate_id(name, email):
    # Generate an ID using email and name
    data = f"{name}_{email}"
    hashed_data = hashlib.sha256(data.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    return hashed_data


def generate_qr_code_redirect_and_id(name, email, redirect_url):
    # Generate ID
    id = generate_id(name, email)
    
    # Construct data for QR code including the GIF URL
    data = f"ID: {id}\nName: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nRedirectURL: {redirect_url}\nGIF: https://gifdb.com/images/high/spongebob-squarepants-done-and-done-2de4g1978uus7pp6.gif"
    
    # Generate QR code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    qr_image = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    
    # Convert image to bytes
    qr_buffer = BytesIO()
    qr_image.save(qr_buffer, format='PNG')
    qr_image_data = qr_buffer.getvalue()
    
    return id, qr_image_data


def upload_to_mongodb_and_csv(id, name, email, redirect_url):
    # Connect to MongoDB
    client = MongoClient(
        'mongo connection string hidden for privacy'
    )
    
    # Select database and collection
    db = client['QRCode-Scans']
    collection = db['People-Who-Scanned']
    
    # Create document to insert
    document = {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'redirect_url': redirect_url
        # Add more fields as needed
    }
    
    # Insert document into collection
    collection.insert_one(document)
    
    # Write data to CSV file
    with open('data.csv', mode='a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([id, name, email, redirect_url])



def send_email_with_qr_code(sender_email, sender_password, recipient_email, qr_code_image_data, id, name, email, redirect_url):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = recipient_email
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = "Your QR Code"
    
    # Email body
    body = f"Hello,\n\nHere is your QR code along with the details:\n\nName: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nRedirect URL: {redirect_url}\n\nBest regards,\nName"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
    
    # Attach QR code image
    image = MIMEImage(qr_code_image_data)
    image.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="qr_code.png")
    msg.attach(image)
    
    # Connect to SMTP server and send email
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(sender_email, sender_password)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()


def read_recipients_from_csv(csv_file):
    recipients = []
    with open(csv_file, mode='r', newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Skip the header row
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) >= 2:
                recipients.append({"name": row[0], "email": row[1]})
            else:
                print(f"Issue with row: {row}")  # Print rows with missing data
    return recipients

# Example usage:

# Path to the CSV file containing recipient information
csv_file_path = "input.csv"
# Read recipients from the CSV file
recipients = read_recipients_from_csv(csv_file_path)
sender_email = "an email hidden for privacy"
sender_password = "app access code hidden for privacy"
# recipients = [
#     # {"name": "name hidden for privacy", "email": "an email hidden for privacy"},
#     # # Add more recipients as needed
# ]

for recipient in recipients:
    name = recipient["name"]
    email = recipient["email"]
    
    # Generate QR code
    id, qr_code_image = generate_qr_code_redirect_and_id(name, email, "https://www.google.com")
    
    # Upload data to MongoDB and CSV
    upload_to_mongodb_and_csv(id, name, email, "https://www.google.com")

    # Send email with QR code image data and details
    send_email_with_qr_code(sender_email, sender_password, email, qr_code_image, id, name, email, "https://www.google.com")

Here is the QR code for reference:

I tried adjusting the ERROR_CORRECT_M to different levels, didn't work. I just want it to display some text that shows the email and name that are encoded within the QR code. It is probably formatted some wrong way, if it is then I have no clue how to fix and what is wrong with the format exactly.
I expected it show me a plain text of the name and email.

I have made it so it encodes the data as a vCard. Here is the code for the generation method:
def generate_qr_code_redirect_and_id(name, email):
    # Generate ID
    id = generate_id(name, email)
    
    # Construct vCard data
    vcard_data = f"BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\nFN:{name}\nEMAIL:{email}\nEND:VCARD"
    
    # Generate QR code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(vcard_data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    qr_image = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    
    # Convert image to bytes
    qr_buffer = BytesIO()
    qr_image.save(qr_buffer, format='PNG')
    qr_image_data = qr_buffer.getvalue()
    
    return id, qr_image_data

